# Update the Multi relation Records in Custom object by using upsert

Tags: apex

I have created one VF page, No I am doing insert and update operation in multiple Custon objects in this page. Now my pbm is I am not able to update the Specimen Records, Its inserting fine. 
Same code I am applying to update other objects its working fine but in Specimen its not working. Please take a look inot code where I am doing mistake ?? I have highlihting the code

```
public with sharing class GenerateCaseNumber {
    public GenerateCaseNumber(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        objPatient = new Patient__c();
        objAccession = new Case_Accession__c();
        objCaseType = new CaseType__c();
        objSpecimen = new Specimen__c();
        objApcase  = new ApCase__c();
        selectedValue = 'testing';
        objComment = new Comment__c();
        objLabs = new Lab__c();
        objClients = new Client__c();
        objPhysician = new Physician__c();
        objFacility = new Facilty__c();
        objPatientList  = new List<Patient__c>();
        objSpecimenTestOrder = new Specimen_TestOrdered__c();
        var = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('field1');
        if (var == null || var == '') {
            TestEditAccession = 'No ID';
        } else {
            TestEditAccession = var ;
            Load_Lab_Client_Facility_Physician(var);
        }


    }

    public void  Load_Lab_Client_Facility_Physician(string AccessionID) {
        //if([select Lab__c,Name from Case_Accession__c where id = :var].Size()>0)
        //{
        objAccession =  [select Lab__c, Facilty__c, Name, Client__c, Physician__c, RequisitionNo__c , Patient__c from Case_Accession__c where id = : AccessionID];
        objPatient  = [select ID, FirstName__c, MiddleName__c, LastName__c, Address__c, Country__c, State__c, City__c, Gender__c , DOB__c from Patient__c where id = : objAccession.Patient__c];
        objApcase = [select ID, Case_Accession__c, CaseNo__c, CaseType__c from Apcase__c where Case_Accession__c = : AccessionID];
        objSpecimen = [select id , ApCase__c, BodySite__c, Description__c, CollectedDate__c, PiecesReceived__c, ReceivedDate__c, RequestDate__c, SpecimenType__c, TransportType__c from Specimen__c where Apcase__c = : objApcase.ID];
        objSpecimenTestOrder  = [select id, Test__c from Specimen_TestOrdered__c where Specimen__c = : objSpecimen .id ];
        if ([select ID, CommentName__c from Comment__c where Case_Accession__c = : AccessionID].Size() == 1) {
            objComment = [select ID, CommentName__c from Comment__c where Case_Accession__c = : AccessionID];

        }
        seletedTestValue        = objSpecimenTestOrder.Test__c;
        * * SelectedSpecimenSite    = objSpecimen.BodySite__c;
        SpecimenDescription     = objSpecimen.Description__c;
        SpecimenPiecesRecieved  = String.Valueof(objSpecimen .PiecesReceived__c);
        SelectedTissueType      = objSpecimen.SpecimenType__c ;
        SelectedTransportType   = objSpecimen.TransportType__c;
        SpecimenID              = objSpecimen.ID;
        ApcaseID                = objApcase.ID; * *
        txtboxSpecimenID        = SpecimenID;

        selectedValue = objApcase.CaseType__c;
        CheckCaseType = false;
        TestFinalCaseNumber = objApcase.CaseNo__c;
        LabSelectedValue = objAccession.Lab__c;
        ClientselectedValue = objAccession.Client__c;
        Facilityselectedvalue = objAccession.Facilty__c;
        Physicianselectedvalue = objAccession.Physician__c;
        PatientID = objAccession.Patient__c;

    }

    public PageReference save() {
        try {
            //string casetypeIdSave = selectedValue;
            //CaseSpecimenList = [select  Id, name from CaseType__c where name =:casetypeIdSave limit 1 ];
            objLabs = [select ID  from Lab__c where ID = : LabSelectedvalue];
            objClients = [select id  from Client__c where ID = : ClientselectedValue];
            objFacility = [select id  from Facilty__c where ID = : Facilityselectedvalue];
            objPhysician = [select id from Physician__c where ID = : Physicianselectedvalue ];
            //handleNewEmail();
            insertPatient();
            upsert objPatient;
            //objApcase.CaseType__c = CaseSpecimenList.id;
            objAccession.Patient__c = objPatient.id;
            objAccession.Lab__c = objLabs.id;
            objAccession.Client__c = objClients.id;
            objAccession.Facilty__c = objFacility.id;
            objAccession.Physician__c = objPhysician.id;
            if (var == null || var == '') {

                Insert objAccession;
            } else {
                objAccession.id = var;
                update objAccession;
            }
            objComment.Case_Accession__c = objAccession.id;
            Insert objComment;
            objApcase  = new ApCase__c();
            objApcase.Case_Accession__c =  objAccession.id;
            objApcase.CaseType__c = selectedValue;
            objApcase.CaseNo__c = TestFinalCaseNumber;
            if (ApcaseId != '') {
                objApcase.id = ApcaseId;
            }
            upsert objApcase;
            * * objSpecimen.Apcase__c = objApcase.id;
            objSpecimen.Description__c = SpecimenDescription;
            objSpecimen.PiecesReceived__c =  Decimal.Valueof(SpecimenPiecesRecieved) ;
            objSpecimen.BodySite__c = SelectedSpecimenSite;
            objSpecimen.TransportType__c = SelectedTransportType;
            objSpecimen.SpecimenType__c = SelectedTissueType ;
            if (SpecimenID != '') {
                //objSpecimen.Apcase__c = objApcase.id;
                objSpecimen.ID = SpecimenID ;
            }
            upsert objSpecimen; * *
            objSpecimenTestOrder.Specimen__c =  objSpecimen.id;
            objSpecimenTestOrder.Test__c = seletedTestValue;
            insert objSpecimenTestOrder;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.debug('\n\nException =' + ex.getMessage() + '\n\n');
        }

        return null;
    }
```

```
<apex:page standardController="Case_Accession__c"  extensions="GenerateCaseNumber" >
<!--<apex:page controller="GenerateCaseNumber"> -->
    <apex:form >
    <apex:actionFunction name="validatedAction" action="{!SearchPatient}" />
        <apex:pageblock title="Accessioning" >
<apex:outputPanel id="detail"  >

             <apex:outputLabel value="{!TestFinalCaseNumber}"></apex:outputLabel>
           &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

              <apex:commandButton Value="Add Specimen"   reRender="detail1"  rendered="{!IF(TestFinalCaseNumber !=null  &&  TestFinalCaseNumber!='',true,false)}">
             </Apex:commandButton>

             </apex:outputPanel>
       </div>
             <apex:outputPanel id="detail1">
            <apex:pageBlockSection id="pageBlockProcessed" rendered="{!RenderedSpecimen}">
             <style type="text/css">
              .dateFormat{float:left; display:inline-block; clear:both}
              th{white-space: normal;}
              </style>

              <table cellspacing="0">
              <tr>

              <th style="text-align:center"> Tissue Type </th>
               <th style="text-align:center"> Specimen Site</th>
               <th style="text-align:center"> Transport Container/ Medium</th>
              <th style="text-align:center">  Pieces Received </th>
              <th style="text-align:center">  Specimen Description/ Procedure </th>
              <th style="text-align:Center">  Collection Date</th>
              <th style="text-align:center">  Recieved Date</th>
              <th style="text-align:center">  Request Date</th>
              <th style="text-align:center">  Test </th>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>
                 <table>
                 <tbody>             
              <apex:selectList multiselect="false" size="1" value="{!SelectedTissueType}"  >
              <apex:selectOptions value="{!TissueTypeOption }"/> 
               </apex:selectList>
               </tbody>
              </table>

</td>            
<td>
                 <table>  
                 <tbody>  
              <apex:selectList multiselect="false" size="1"  value="{!SelectedSpecimenSite}" >
              <apex:selectOptions value="{!SpecimenSiteOption }"/> 
               </apex:selectList>
               </tbody>
               </table>

</td>   
 <td>
                 <table>
                 <tbody>             
              <apex:selectList multiselect="false" size="1" value="{!SelectedTransportType}"  >
              <apex:selectOptions value="{!TransportTypeOption }"/> 
               </apex:selectList>
               </tbody>
              </table>

</td>          
<td>
            <table>
            <tbody>
            <apex:inputText id="txtPiecesRecieved" value="{!SpecimenPiecesRecieved}" />
            </tbody>
            </table>
</td>            
  <td>
            <table>
            <tbody>
            <apex:inputTextarea id="txtSpecimenDescription" value="{!SpecimenDescription}" /> 

            </tbody>
            </table>
</td>
<td>
            <table>
            <tbody>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:inputField value="{!objSpecimen.CollectedDate__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            </tbody>
            </table>
</td>  
<td>
            <table>
            <tbody>
              <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:inputField value="{!objSpecimen.ReceivedDate__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </tbody>
            </table>
</td> 
 <td>
            <table>
            <tbody>
              <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:inputField value="{!objSpecimen.RequestDate__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </tbody>
            </table>
</td> 
<td>
                 <table>
                 <tbody>             
              <apex:selectList multiselect="false" size="1" value="{!seletedTestValue}"  >
              <apex:selectOptions value="{!LoadTests }"/> 
               </apex:selectList>
               </tbody>
              </table>

</td>  
               </tr>
              </table>

               </apex:pageBlockSection> 
             </apex:outputPanel>
      <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                  <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Done"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:inputText value="{!var}"/>
            <apex:inputText value="{!txtboxSpecimenID }"/>
        </apex:pageblock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: You haven't mentioned the error you are getting. One thing with Upsert is that you need an external ID field in the custom object that you are trying to update.

Comment: @Prady :: I am not getting any error actually. Just record is not updating as ecpected

Comment: @RichardN:: I am not getting any error actually. Just record is not updating as expected. and what do u mean by external id field here,, I am not giving in any object the external ID still they are getting updated fine. But pbm is in Specimen only ??????

Comment: Can you check your debug logs to see if there is something logged in there. Check if the exception is printed on the debug logs as you are already catching the exception

Comment: @Prady::: Thanks prady I got the solution after checking the log
!!!!!!!!!!!!
Cheers
Raman